# Is {from: thesponsor, value: 10000000, gas: 3000000} a msg object in solidity?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

In the [IBM Example](https://developer.ibm.com/clouddataservices/2016/05/19/block-chain-technology-smart-contracts-and-ethereum/) of Ethereum smart contract, there is this following code:

```
personal.unlockAccount(thesponsor,"password"); 
ss.pledge("Good luck with the run!", {from: thesponsor, value: 10000000, gas: 3000000});
```

However, the pledge function is not a payable modifier and it only accepts one arguments as the parameter:

```
function pledge(bytes32 _message) {
  if (msg.value == 0 || complete || refunded) throw;
  pledges[numPledges] = Pledge(msg.value, msg.sender, _message);
  numPledges++;
}
```

So, is solidity automatically seeing {from: thesponsor, value: 10000000, gas: 3000000} as a msg object that transfer ethers from my account?

I just found this feature a bit werid. What if I wrote a json object that happens to contain the keywords "from" and "value", would I accidentally tranfer any funds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you have found a solution to your question half a year down but if you have not then..

Yes, you are correct in your observation that the `{from: thesponsor, value: 10000000, gas: 3000000}` is interpreted as a `transactionObject`. This is because any `transaction` on Ethereum that causes a state change (meaning you create, update or delete data) requires a `transactionObject` such as the one seen above to allow your code to be executed on the blockchain.

In the snippet below, you can see that the `pledge` function causes a state change on lines 4 and 5. That alone requires that you provide `gas` for the transaction. In addition, the `pledge` makes use of `msg.value` which is the value of the Ethereum amount that you are sending in the pledge, denoted by the `value`.

```
1  // add a new pledge
2  function pledge(bytes32 _message) {
3    if (msg.value == 0 || complete || refunded) throw;
4    pledges[numPledges] = Pledge(msg.value, msg.sender, _message);
5    numPledges++;
6  }
```

Regarding your second question, check out https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendtransaction to see the structure of a `transactionObject`. Functions in Ethereum (if they make state changes) will take in the parameters for the function first, followed by the `transactionObject` behind. As such, simply make sure you don't write the `transactionObject` accidentally as it will be interpreted as a transaction.